# Centering my list of equations

Tags: lists

Hello I am currently working on my thesis, and I need every title to be centered, howerver, the way I made my list of equations title isn't centering as you can see in the picture [image].

the code I am using to generate this list is:

```
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\normalsize List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
```

If I try to center it using the `\listequationsname` it than throws off its place in the TOC. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Why centering? Just to make it less readable?

Comment: No because that’s the format my school requires for it to be acceptable, personally I agree with you it’s less readable.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, all I had to do is

```
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\begin{center}\normalsize List of Equations\end{center}}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
```

and then

add this to the table of contents:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Equations}
```